# R giving LAS file read error

Tags: r, lidar, rlidar

I am using the rLiDAR package to read some LAS files, but the readLAS function in rLiDAR is giving the following error:

```
Error in readLAS("D:/LAS_Files/test_1.las", short = TRUE) : 
  no records left to read
```

However, the function readLAS works just fine with test.las (small file-162 MB), but throws an error with the test_1 (big size, >500 MB)
.The code is as follows:

```
#Read the LAS files
library(rLiDAR)
las<-readLAS("D:/Summer_2019/NRS_Project/01_data/01_las_2013/test.las",short = TRUE)
las_1<-readLAS("D:/LAS_Files/test_1.las",short = TRUE)
```

Comment: Do you have any other tools (outside of R) that *can* read the file to test if its a good file or not?

Comment: Yes, this test_1 file and other LAS files related to it are working fine with Fusion scripts and even with the readLAS function in lidR, this error is only happening with the readLAS function of rLiDAR.

Comment: It might be a bug in `rLiDAR`. That doesn't seem to have been updated since 2017 and there's no reference to a development version on github or elsewhere in the description and there's no bug tracker. Email the maintainer?