# readLAS error in rLiDAR - can only read from a binary connection

Tags: r, lidar, rlidar

I am having las file read error while using the `rLiDAR` package in R. My code is as follows:

```r
LASfile <- system.file("C:/03_processing/Test_LAS/LASexample1.las")
rLAS<-readLAS(LASfile,short=TRUE)
#> Error in readBin(con, "raw", size = 1, n = 4, endian = "little") : 
#>   can only read from a binary connection
#> In addition: Warning message:
#>   In file(LASfile, open = "rb") :
#>   file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

Now I know this question has already been addressed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365454/r-giving-las-file-read-error), but I am still having the error. As you can see I literally renamed the variables and the .las file according to the example given in the PDF of this package for the `readLAS()` function, as I thought maybe the names are hard coded in this package. But I am still getting this error, and no `lidR` is not loaded in R at the moment, so there are no conflicts there either. Can someone please help me with this error? Also, can I use any naming convention for the .las files and the variables with regards to importing and reading the LAS files? Furthermore, I noticed the following, is that normal?

[image]

And finally, the las files are working fine with Fusion, so there is no problem with the input .las files.

**Update 1:**
Upon using `LASfile <- "C:/03_processing/Test_LAS/LASexample1.las`" and then `rLAS<-readLAS(LASfile,short=TRUE)`, I am getting this now: `Error in readLAS(LASfile, short = TRUE) : no records left to read.`
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `system.file`? Have you checked the content of `LASfile`? Yes you did it and  you noticed it is empty (`""`). Simply use `LASfile <- "C:/03_processing/Test_LAS/LASexample1.las"`

Comment: After your update: you have already asked the question here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365454/r-giving-las-file-read-error and Spacedman answered to it.

Comment: Yes, I thought of using the exact syntax as given in the readLAS example of rLiDAR Manual, and maybe I won't encounter the error again. But it seems that it really is a bug, and I guess it would be best to just use lidR then for reading LAS files.

Comment: `rLiDAR::readLAS()` has only a partial support of the LAS format and relies on old R code not maintained. It is not surprising it fails at reading some files